# Python Connection blpapi issues/inconsistencies

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I've installed python 3.9 venv and install `blpapi` via:

`pip install --index-url=https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple blpapi`

([source](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/))

When I run the following example on this venv I'm getting connection issues:

```
import blpapi
options = blpapi.SessionOptions()
options.setServerHost('localhost')
options.setServerPort(8194)
session = blpapi.Session(options)
session.start()
```

Error:

```
apicm_apiconnector.cpp:389 ApiConnector::socketConnectorCallback localhost: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:8194, status=1, error 8 connect event failed

ERROR blpapi_sessionimpl.cpp:2541 blpapi.session.{1} Failed to start session. { ErrorInfo=[ source = "ApiConnector" code = 8 category = "IO_ERROR" errorMessage = "connect event failed" subcategory = NULL ] RequestId=NULL }
```

The weird issue is when I install the same package on to the local python interpreter it works. Local python is python 3.10 and is able to connect.

Any ideas if I'm missing any critical steps in my installation of the package?

I tried to install it in to a separate local python environment and it works.

Comment: I would check the PATH within your env. It probably needs to include `c:\blp\dapi`. The longer story is that the api doesn't talk directly to the Bloomberg servers: it talks to a local `bbcomm.exe` process. `bbcomm.exe` is not started automatically by the Bloomberg Terminal, instead the api loads a helper dll (whose name escapes me), which starts `bbcomm.exe` and allows for session connections. If your env doesn't have the right PATH, it won't find the dll, and so won't start `bbcomm.exe` (check in Task Manager).

Comment: A way to check this is to open the Bloomberg addin in Excel, and do a BDP() call. This should trigger the launch of `bbcomm.exe` and your Python code should be able to connect to it.

Comment: `blpdapisup_64.dll` ... you might want to try copying this dll to wherever you have `blpapi3_64.dll`. As I recall, the api will try and load this additional dll from the same directory that it loaded `blpapi3_64.dll`.

Comment: The issue seems to be that I needed to restart my server. My BBG setup was new. When in doubt, restart!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just had to restart my server...

When it doubt, restart....

Answer (score 0):

The latest update broke Blpapi on Python 3.9 and below. Has something to do with the C++ SDK needing to be updated. C++ isn't used in the 3.10+ versions of Blpapi, which is why you're not having issues on 3.10+

You can update the SDK from Bloomberg's website, or update your python environment.